# JMeter with Not Gui mode for ant task doesn't run on slave node

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, jmeter

I have configured JMeter cluster testing according to this manual - [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Both machines are ***CentOS 6*** with disabled firewalls and have the same version of JMeter.

Project has built with JMeter's ***Java Samples***:

[image]

All calls are going to back end. Through RMI calls, if to be accurate.

***Master node configuration***:

Updated `jmeter.properties` with slave IP

> Run Jenkins job -> ant calls [JMeter ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) -> launches test on Jmeter (it has built jar with java's sampler).
>
> JDK 1.7.25 / ant 1.9.4 / JMeter 2.11;

***Slave node configuration:***

> JDK 1.7.90 / ant 1.7.1 / JMeter 2.11;

Started `jmeter-server`.

After launching test job. It executes only on the master node. Request sending to slave node didn't happen.
I couldn't get a klue why this happenning.

Here is snippet from ***ant task***:

```
<target name="jmeter-test" depends="jmeter-init, is_run_remote">
    <jmeter jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
            testplan="${basedir.unix}/${test.testplan.path}"
            resultlog="${basedir.unix}/${results.report.jmeter.generated.path}"
            failureproperty="test_failed"
            runremote="${is_remote}">
        <!-- jvm settings -->
        <jvmarg value="-Xms${jvm.xms}"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx${jvm.xmx}"/>
        <!-- jmeter remoting properties -->
        <property name="remote_hosts" value="${remote_hosts}" />
        <property name="client.rmi.localport" value="${client.rmi.localport}" />
        <property name="java.rmi.server.hostname" value="${java.rmi.server.hostname}" />
        <property name="server.exitaftertest" value="${server.exitaftertest}" />
        <property name="client.rmi.localport" value="${client.rmi.localport}" remote="true" />
        <property name="server.rmi.localport" value="${server.rmi.localport}" remote="true" />
        <property name="sample_sender_client_configured" value="${sample_sender_client_configured}" remote="true" />
        <property name="mode" value="${remote.results.sending.mode}" remote="true" />
        <property name="asynch.batch.queue.size" value="${asynch.batch.queue.size}" remote="true" />
```

The main difference from `jmeter.log` is that usual test goes through compiling Samplers:

```
jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.functions.StringFromFile: setParameters(${LISTING_USERS_CSV}) 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: post.PostFreightSearchSampler. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: post.PostVehicleSearchSampler. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: post.region.PostFreightRegionalSearchSampler. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: post.region.PostVehicleRegionalSearchSampler. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: post.country.PostFreightCountrySearchSampler. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: post.country.PostVehicleCountrySearchSampler. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: search.execute.ExecuteFreightSearch. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: search.execute.ExecuteVehicleSearch. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: search.execute.ExecuteFreightSearch. Uses tearDownTest: false 
2016/07/19 14:36:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: search.execute.ExecuteVehicleSearch. Uses tearDownTest: false
```

At case of remoting run it has different behavior:

```
jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 127.0.0.1 basedir='.'
... set the run props
jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 127.0.0.1 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Remote engines have been started 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Started remote host:  127.0.0.1 (1469447953598) 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =      1 in     0s = ******/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:     0 Err:     1 (100.00%) 
2016/07/25 14:59:13 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Finished remote host: 127.0.0.1 (1469447953740)
```

***How to make distributed testing?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was next:

1. on the Slaves machines correct `jmeter-server`:

   DIRNAME=`dirname $0`

   RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.6.216.XXX

   ${DIRNAME}/jmeter ${RMI_HOST_DEF} -Dserver_port=60000 -s -j jmeter-server.log "$@"

just uncomment ***RMI_HOST_DEF*** and assign the IP address of this machine, and specify port - 60000 (default one).

On the main workstation (Windows 8.1) adapted test plan to Slaves architecture (CentOS 6) - updated all resources paths to Unix style and locate them the same way for everyone slave instance.

2. Correct the `remote-hosts` with IP addresses and port for main mashine:

   remote_hosts=10.6.216.XXX:60000,10.6.216.XXX:60000
3. Start `jmeter-server` on all slaves:

   [user@ECSC00103331 ~]$ jmeter-server
   Using local port: 60000
   Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:10.6.216.40:60000,objID:[2f100b79:15630b4bb73:-7fff, 6552789263830402879]]]

   Also increased `ulimit` value for every instance:

> ulimit -u 50000

By default, it was ***1024***. You can check it with `ulimit -a` command.

4. Start run from JMeter UI - `Run` -> `Remote Start All`. Snippet from CentOS console:

   Starting the test on host 10.6.216.XXX:60000 @ Thu Jul 28 11:53:12 MSK 2016 (1469695992526)
   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/etc/jmeter/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Fx-Performance-Tests-RMI/workspace/fx-performance-tests/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
   Uncaught Exception org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: Could not return sample. See log file for details.

It works even with this strange exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run "jmeter-server" on both Jmeter master & client machine.

and then execute your script like this.

./jmeter -n -t jmeterscript.jmx -R 172.0.0.1(master-ip),(slave-ip) -l logfile.jtl

reference:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html